# Disappearing components in JTextPane

Tags: java

I have simplified my problem by taking out all code that's not relevant to the problem.  This leaves me with 2 simple java classes:

1. BugFrameTest.  Stores a DefaultStyledDocument that is null initially.  Has a button which opens up a dialog box, the second class.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class BugFrameTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private DefaultStyledDocument sectionTextDoc = null;

    public BugFrameTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Click for Dialog");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // java - get screen size using the Toolkit class
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        double screenWidth = screenSize.getWidth();
        double screenHeight = screenSize.getHeight();

        double percentReduce = 0.90;

        Dimension dimension = new Dimension();
        dimension.setSize(
                (int) (screenWidth * percentReduce),
                (int) (screenHeight * percentReduce));

        SectionJDialog2 sectionJDialog2 = null;

        sectionJDialog2 = new SectionJDialog2(
                this, true, sectionTextDoc);

        sectionJDialog2.setLocationRelativeTo(this);

        sectionJDialog2.setVisible(true);

        // After closing we store the document to display again.
        sectionTextDoc
                = (DefaultStyledDocument) sectionJDialog2.getDocument();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BugFrameTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BugFrameTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BugFrameTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BugFrameTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new BugFrameTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

2. SectionJDialog2.  The dialog box contains a JTextPane and a button which inserts an empty JTextArea into the JTextPane.  On closing the dialog, the JTextPane's DefaultStyledDocument is stored in BugFrameTest.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;

public class SectionJDialog2 extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();

    public SectionJDialog2(
            java.awt.Frame parent,
            boolean modal,
            DefaultStyledDocument doc) {

        super(parent, modal);

        initComponents();

        pack();

        if (doc == null) {
            doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
        }

        this.jTextPane1.setDocument(doc);
    }

    public DefaultStyledDocument getDocument() {
        return (DefaultStyledDocument) this.jTextPane1.getDocument();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        textAreaButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                closeDialogHandler(evt);
            }
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowClosing(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        textAreaButton.setText("Insert Text Area");
        textAreaButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                textAreaButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 551, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(textAreaButton)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(textAreaButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 251, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void closeDialogHandler(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                    

    }                                   

    private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
        this.dispose();
    }                                  

    private void textAreaButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        JTextArea quoteField = new JTextArea();
        quoteField.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        quoteField.setLineWrap(true);

        jTextPane1.insertComponent(quoteField);
    }                                              

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton textAreaButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

On first opening SectionJDialog2, all is well.  You can insert a JTextArea and text with no issue.  You then close the dialog.

On re-opening SectionJDialog2 (by pressing the button in BugFrameTest), the text and JTextArea are still there.  However if you now press the return key immediately after the JTextArea, the JTextArea vanishes (at least from display).  You can close and re-open the dialog and the JTextArea reappears.

My question then is simply, how do I stop the JTextArea from disappearing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is a bug in java.  I have found a workaround however, after writing the serializable StyledDocument out to file and then reading the object back before opening the dialog, I no longer get the problem.

```
// Serialize data object to a file
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(filePath) );
out.writeObject(doc);
out.close();


FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
        filePath
);
ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
doc = (StyledDocument) reader.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

JTextArea is not meant to be used without a JScrollPane parent.  Without that parent, it wants to be as wide as possible, which is causing layout issues for your JTextPane.

A JTextArea is a text component which allows multiple rows of text.  Is that really what you want?  If you just want a one-line text component, you should use a [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextField.html).

If you insist on using a JTextArea, [set its preferred column count](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setColumns%28int%29), and place it in a JScrollPane:

```
JTextArea quoteField = new JTextArea();
quoteField.setColumns(10);
quoteField.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
quoteField.setLineWrap(true);

jTextPane1.insertComponent(new JScrollPane(quoteField));
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the problem is still happening unfortunately.  It's not just JTextArea components but any component in fact; I added a second button on the dialog to insert buttons into the JTextPane and the exact same behaviour happens with the buttons, no JTextAreas inserted in my test.

Comment: JButton jButton = new JButton("Some long text on a button.");
        jTextPane1.insertComponent(jButton);